# O tipo 'http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe:TNFe' não está declarado

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, asp.net-core-web-api

Bom dia, geralmente eu evito ao máximo fazer perguntas aqui no fórum pois sempre encontro muitas resposta que suprem minha situação.

Estou fazendo uma integração com a Sefaz, utilizando o Ws de Autorização da NFe 4.00, mas quando vou fazer a validação do meu XML é retornado o erro:

> Type 'http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe:TNFe' is not declared

Criei meu projeto no Asp.Net Core (Web Api) e esse é o código que uso pra validar:

```
XmlReaderSettings xmlReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
xmlReaderSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
xmlReaderSettings.Schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
xmlReaderSettings.XmlResolver = new XmlUrlResolver() { Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials };
xmlReaderSettings.Schemas.Add(null, localSchema);
xmlReaderSettings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(delegate (object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
{
     var ex = new Exception(string.Format("Falha ao validar Xml! Linha: {0}, Coluna: {1}, Mensagem: {2}",
     e.Exception.LineNumber, e.Exception.LinePosition, e.Exception.Message));
     ex.Data.Add("statusCode", HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
     throw ex;
 });

 using (var stringReader = new StringReader(xml.InnerXml))
 {
     var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader, xmlReaderSettings);
     while (xmlReader.Read()) { }                    
     xmlReader.Close();
```

Lembrando que:

- O mesmo código funciona em projetos diferentes do Core;
- O erro acontece na seguinte linha "var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader, xmlReaderSettings);"
- Todos os schemas da NFe 4.00 estão atualizados;
- Sei que o erro não é no XML pois ele funciona tranquilo numa versão de um projeto antigo;
- Já testei algumas dicas de outros que perguntaram e não funcionou;
- Os schemas que utilizo, podem ser baixados no seguinte link: "http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/PORTAL/exibirArquivo.aspx?conteudo=CoNA9VIgZ3E="

Agradeço desde já a ajuda.

Comment: Olá Leonardo, em qual linha ocorre a exceção?

Answer (score 1):

Tive o mesmo problema. Para conseguir resolver adicionei no `xmlReaderSettings` as referências do xsd de notas.

Você pode encontrar a lista atualizada de *schemas* no [site da Receita Federal](https://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/listaConteudo.aspx?tipoConteudo=/fwLvLUSmU8=).

No meu caso ficou assim:

```
XmlReaderSettings Settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
Settings.Schemas.Add("http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe", XmlReader.Create(assets.Open("Schemas/nfe_v4.00.xsd")));
Settings.Schemas.Add("http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe", XmlReader.Create(assets.Open("Schemas/leiauteNFe_v4.00.xsd")));
Settings.Schemas.Add("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#", XmlReader.Create(assets.Open("Schemas/xmldsig-core-schema_v1.01.xsd")));
Settings.Schemas.Add("http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe", XmlReader.Create(assets.Open("Schemas/tiposBasico_v4.00.xsd")));
Settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallBack);
Settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
try
{
    XmlReader validator = XmlReader.Create("/storage/emulated/0/certificados/NotaTeste.xml", Settings)
}
catch (Exception EX)
{
    string ex = EX.ToString();
}

private static void ValidationCallBack(object sender, ValidationEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Warning)
        Console.WriteLine("\tWarning: Matching schema not found.  No validation occurred." + args.Message);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("\tValidation error: " + args.Message);
    }
}
```